# How to attach a description to each ActionMethod in a Controller (ASP.net MVC)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes, custom-attributes, actionmethod

So recently, I came up with a way to dynamically build a nav-bar menu where the Controller (And its Index ActionMethod) would be listed in a horizontal bar at the top of each page (via Site.Master) but also based on the user's assigned roles. Each Controller listed would also list (in a vertical drop-down) the ActionMethods available to the user.

See here for the code I wrote to **[create an Extended Controller class for ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999918/asp-net-mvc-how-to-find-controllers-with-authorize-attributes-using-reflection/3023327#3023327)** which solved the above mentioned problem.

I realized that I also want to automatically create a default Index page for each Controller that lists all the ActionMethods available and a short 1 or 2 sentence description of each ActionMethod, but was pondering how to attach the description to the ActionMethod.

My assumption is that I need to do 3 things:

(1) Create my own Attribute, say, Description and decorate each ActionMethod in each Controller like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public class SomeController : ExtController
{
   [Description("This method adjusts all of your widgets making them better.")]
   public ActionResult TweakWidgets()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

(2) Create a **public ActionResult Index()** method in my base class (ExtController) which will be used by every class inheriting ExtController to show a listing of the ActionMethods and their Descriptions available to that user.

(3) Create an Index.aspx View in Views/Shared that will build such a page.

Is this a sensible approach? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a reasonable approach.

However there already is a [DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) class in System.ComponentModel that you could probably leverage.  There's some example code for reflecting on that property as well on the manual page.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the pointer. I hate re-inventing the wheel and wasn't sure if there was already a Description attribute.

Comment: Intellisense wasn't pulling up anything for me, but I didn't have System.ComponentModel referenced, so that would make sense... Thanks!