# FormCollection in MVC4 with Html Actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink, formcollection, querystringparameter

I am using HTML `ActionLink` in MVC4. I need to remove `QueryStrings` using `formCollection`. How to Use it?

Here is my Code:

```
       <div class="mainNav">
            <nav>
                  <ul>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Query.Count - 1; i++)
                        {                            
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink(Query[i].Parent_Menu,"ManageContent","Home", new { CmsFid = Query[i].CMSFunction_Id,ParentMenu=Query[i].Parent_Menu  },new { @style = "color:#FFF;text-decoration:none" })</li>

                        }
                        @for(int i=Query.Count-1;i<Query.Count;i++)
                        {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink(Query[i].Parent_Menu,"ManageContent","Home", new { CmsFid = Query[i].CMSFunction_Id,ParentMenu=Query[i].Parent_Menu  },new {@class="last", @style = "color:#FFF;text-decoration:none" })</li>
                        }
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: Would you please consider rephrasing or expanding on your question? At the moment I'm not sure what you're doing, what you want or what you're trying to achieve. Try imagining that you're answering this question. Also read [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: please can you tell the problem you are facing

Comment: here I am dynamically binding menu from DataBase . when Click on menu item bind data based on ID. As of now I am using querystring Parameters to pass iD to controller. But now i want to use ormcollection to remove querystrings.

Comment: If you are generating dynamic menus then why do you need `Query` parameters?  Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498255/how-to-creating-a-dynamic-sub-menus-by-sub-categories/22503615#22503615) answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you will be able to get the formCollection elements in your action (using Html.ActionLink). Also if you are able you may need to parse them or type cast  them for your    properties. so I recomend you to have an action method  like

```
 public ActionResult  ManageContent(int CmsFid,string ParentMenu)
    {
    }
```

well you can use formCollection for form post where you may have many data

if its a form post you can use like this

```
 public ActionResult YourPostMethod(FormCollection formData)
{
   int CmsFid=int.Parse(formData["CmsFid"]);
}
```